# Location icons to follow responsive background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a website in which I have a responsive background image with some houses, and I have some location icons (like google for example) which are above some houses.

Is there anyway those location icons could follow the background to keep their position above the certain houses on which they were placed? Thank you.

Here's the code for the responsive background image:

```
body {
  background: url(../img/backgroundLarge.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

The location icons are placed as a normal img tag like so and styled with padding for their position:

```
<img src="img/locationIcon.png">
```

Some clever jQuery or JavaScript perhaps?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do some guess-and-check work to figure out the percentage width/height of the body at which you want to absolute position your icons above the houses -- but then you could just use CSS.

```
#someIcon {
 left:50%;
 top:30%;
}
```

You probably will need to factor in the icon image size as well -- which you could do by guess-and-checking in CSS until it looks nice or calculating the margin to set by using JavaScript.

If you mean "responsive" in the sense that the image itself is animated (like a .GIF), then you're going to have a tougher time. You could use [SVG Paths](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html) and animate the icons to move along with your background, but you may also just have better luck ripping the moving parts out of the image and using something similar to [Parallax](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. By responsive image I mean it's a normal jpg file that will resize automatically to fill the whole screen. You are on the right track I think, I also added position: absolute; and so far I think it works. I still think there's a better way to do this

Comment: @Andrei P: Please feel free to post your own answer if you come up with a better one. I hope that there is a better answer, but if all you are doing is scaling the image, then percentage positions are probably your best bet. G'Luck.

Comment: "This is not even close" -- why not? It should be agnostic of resolution. Please explain.